# Find the loss percentage on the remaining if the overall loss is 14% (a GMAT exam question)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Tinkawala purchased the articles for Rs. 123684. He sold 60% of those at a profit of 16.66% and the rest at loss. Find the loss percentage on the remaining if the overall loss is 14%.

What I did
Let the CP be x
SP=$0.60*(1+50/3*x+0.40*(1-p/100)=0.86x$
but my answer isn't right.

Where am I wrong

Comment: $(49473.6- 49473.6\times \frac{x}{100})+(74210.4 +12363.45)=123684-17315.76$

Answer (score 0):

```
100% of the amount is 123684
60% of the amount is 74210.40
40% of the amount is 49473.60

to calculate the total loss amount
123684÷100×14=17315.76
so. 
to calculate the loss percentage of the 40% of the amount.(49473.60)
17315.76÷49473.60×100=35%
```